# Special characters in a glossary entry cause an error if printed uppercase

Tags: characters, uppercase, glossary

I have a glossary entry that defines a word beginning with a special character "ś". Unfortunately I need to use this entry at the beginning of a sentence so it must be written uppercase. This causes some errors while compiling a document.
Minimal working example of this problem is attached below.
My question is: do I need to rewrite my sentence so the entry with the special character appears in the middle or is it possible to make the below example work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{entry1}
{
    name=swat ,
    description={A police tactical unit.}
}

\newglossaryentry{entry2}
{
    name=świat,
    description={The word 'world' in Polish.}
}

\title{How to create a glossary}
\author{ }
\date{ }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

This entry is fine whether I print it uppercase or not \Gls{entry1}. 
This one causes an error if I try to print it uppercase \Gls{entry2}. 

\clearpage

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue arises as internally the `glossaries` package is trying to make the first character uppercase using effectively

```latex
\MakeUppercase świat
```

That fails with an 8-bit engine as only the first *byte* of the input is grabbed. You need to use a function capable of dealign with such 8-bit input correctly. Try adding

```
\makeatletter
\def\@gls@makefirstuc#1{\MakeTitlecase{#1}}
\makeatother
```

to your source. For older LaTeX releases you may need

```
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\@gls@makefirstuc#1{\text_titlecase:n{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
```

to access the underlying functionality.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. It changes the error though. With your solution it is `undefined control sequence. ... I try to print it upper case  \Gls{entry2}`.

Comment: @zajer \MakeTitlecase requires a current LaTeX.

Comment: @zajer It works here with an up-to-date TL 2022. I suspect you have an older system: I'll suggest an approach there.

Comment: @JosephWright I have to make it compilable on Overleaf and it seems the latest version available is 2021. Is there any way to make it work there or redefine `\MakeTitlecase` ?

Comment: @zajer Tom from Overleaf Support here. We hope to deploy TeX Live 2022 pretty soon, and you should be able to get `\MakeTitlecase` to work in Overleaf once it's deployed and you switch the project to it in the project's Menu. I hope this helps!

Comment: Acutally, TeX Live 2022 is out now! https://www.overleaf.com/blog/tex-live-2022-now-available

Comment: @yo' Thanks for the feedback. It is certainly encouraging to know that Overleaf staff actively participates in this community.

Comment: @zajer Thanks for the nice words, we try our best! The truth is, a few team members were active in this community before joining Overleaf, including me :-)